# How would these methods be setup to increment and decrement the last number in an array by 1? Java

Tags: java, arrays, int, increment, decrement

For this project I am creating arrays, each with 50 elements, each element with a value between 0 and 9, and using those arrays called "BigIntegers" in addition, subtraction, multiplication and division. There are a few smaller methods called increment and decrement that I am having trouble figuring out. This is the code that I have done...

```
public class BigInteger {   

    int[] BigInteger = new int[50];

    //xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    //x BigInteger(): creates a BigInteger of all 0's                x
    //xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx   
    public BigInteger() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        BigInteger[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    //xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    //x BigInteger(n): creates a BigInteger the size of n            x
    //xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx    
    public BigInteger(int n) {
         for (int i = 49; i > 0; i--) {
            BigInteger[i] = n%10;
            n = n/10;
        }
        BigInteger[0] = n;
    }

    public int[] getBigInteger() {
        return BigInteger;
    }

    public BigInteger(BigInteger n) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            BigInteger[i] = n.getBigInteger()[i];
        }
    }

    //xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    //x print(): prints out each element of the BigInteger array     x
    //xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    public void print() {
        int index = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < BigInteger.length; i++) { 
            if (BigInteger[i] == 0) { index = 0; }
            else { index = i; break; }
        }

        for(int i = index; i < BigInteger.length; i++) { 
            System.out.print(BigInteger[i] + " ");
        }   
    }

    public void decrement() {
        int last = BigInteger.length;
        for(int i = last; i < 50; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {  }
            else last = BigInteger[last] - 1;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        BigInteger big = new BigInteger(50);
        BigInteger big2 = new BigInteger();
        BigInteger big3 = new BigInteger(602345812);
}
```

The functions of these methods are:

•   void increment( ) --- increase the value of the invoking object by 1

•   void decrement( ) --- decrement the value of the invoking object by 1

I've spent numerous hours trying to figure out these, what seem to be, easy methods. Any help or advice? 
Thanks I.

Comment: Note: calling your class `BigInteger` is confusing, as there is [a well-known class of that name](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html); calling a variable in that class `BigInteger` (whose type is not `BigInteger` but `int[]`) as well is positively baffling.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may be asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.  (Even if this isn't homework, please consider the advice anyway.)

Comment: @AndyTurner positively baffling indeed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question well, you should try this (with remarks from @Andy Turner and @Yang Li) as a starting point:

```
public void increment() {
    for (int i = BigInteger.length - 1; i; i--)
      if (BigInteger[i] < 9) {
        BigInteger[i]++;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < BigInteger.length; j++)
          BigInteger[j] = 0;
        break;
      }
      else if (i == 0)
        // cannot increment 9
}

public void decrement() {
    for (int i = BigInteger.length - 1; i; i--)
      if (BigInteger[i] > 0) {
        BigInteger[i]--;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < BigInteger.length; j++)
          BigInteger[j] = 9;
        break;
      }
      else if (i == 0)
        // cannot decrement 0
}
```

This will increment / decrement the last `int` element of your `BigInteger` array, where `BigInteger.length - 1` is the index of the last element in your array.

Comment: And what happens when the digits exceed 9 or fall below 0?

Comment: Sure, this was an initial answer, let me fix this :)

Answer (score 0):

There are already some answers by this post, but you need to be careful because some of these answers don't deal with overflow. If the last digit is 9 and you increment it by 1, it will overflow, if the last digit is 0 and you subtract, it will also be problematic.

You should also consider the case where all the digits in your BigInteger array are '9'. In this case if you increment it by one, no more rooms would be allowed in your array. Same thing may happen if all the digits in BigInteger are '0' and you want to subtract it by 1. For those cases you should probably throw an error.

**Update**

I have implemented the recursive way to increment the big integer.
Please note that I have handled the case where all digits in BigInteger are '9'. You should check if this input is expected, otherwise you should remove this check.

```
public void increment() {
    increment(BigInteger.length-1);
}

private void increment(int index) {
    if (index < 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("BigInteger maximum capacity reached!");
    }
    if (BigInteger[index] < 9) {
        BigInteger[index]++;
    } else {
        BigInteger[index] = 0;
        increment(--index);
    }
}
```

Basically this will keep looking for leading digits until it is less than 9 and then increment that digit, during the process it will set any '9' it encounters to '0'.

I didn't implement the "decrease" method because I think it would be good that you can come up with your own solution.

Comment: Thank you for the help! This definitely allows me to understand how to do this. So would decrement be easier to do recursively like increment? (I'm pretty new to recursion)

Comment: I personally believe that recursion is easier to think and understand. However any recursion can be re-written into loop. So if you are not comfortable with recursion, loop is another choice. So yes, you can definitely write decrement with recursion. I wouldn't say that would be easier, just go with any method that you are comfortable with. Happy coding!